# Iterating a Dictionary with String, Any pair in Swift

Tags: swift, list, dictionary, enumeration

I have written this function that reads in values from a text file and stores them in a dictionary. The dictionary is formatted as: `[String : Any]`. Each key in the dictionary is associated with a Zipped list. The function returns the value associated for that key if the value `symbol` is present as a key in the dictionary. The function works correctly and is able to return a value for that associated key in the dictionary. However I am unable to iterate the returned list due to the error `type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'`. I've checked the type of the returned value from the function which is displayed as `Zip2Sequence<Array<String>, Array<Any>>`. Using `dump` to show the variable on the console also shows the the returned value is a list type. Any idea as to why I can't iterate the returned list?

The variable `_element_data` is defined as; `var _element_data : Dictionary<String, Any>`

```
func lookup_element_data( symbol : String, copy:Bool = true) -> Any{

        if _element_data.count == 0{

            let Keys : [String] = ["Symbol", "Name", "Z", "Mass", "r_cov", "e_affinity", "p_eig", "s_eig", "Abundance", "el_neg", "ion_pot"];

            //Gets all the data from the file element_data.txt as a 2D string array
            //_get_data_rows works correclty
            let elementDataFile = _get_data_rows(filename: "element_data");

            for items in elementDataFile{

                //Take each item in the list and:
                //filter the items out into Optional(number) and nil
                var convertedNumerals = items.map({ float_or_Nil(x: $0) });
                var tempList : [String] = Array(items[0...1]); //store each string in an array of type Any
                let tempListBack : [Float?] = Array(convertedNumerals[2...]);

                var convertedList : [Any] = tempList;
                convertedList.append(tempListBack); //Combining the two lists together

                //Zipping keys with items together
                let zipped = zip(Keys, convertedList);

                //Asign value with key element data converted to String
                //Each key is assoicated with a list of pairs of each element
                _element_data[tempList[0]] = zipped;
             }
        }

        //If the item is a key in the dictionary
        if _element_data[symbol] != nil{

            //Return the value assoicated with this specific symbol
            return _element_data[symbol]!;
        }else{
            return [];
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why not just type the dictionary as `[String : Zip2Sequence<Array<String>, Array<Any>>]` instead of `[String : Any]`, if that's the actual type?

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't think of that. Cheers! all good now